# Getting hex through Cin

Tags: c++, hex

Why doesn't this code work?

```
int x;
cin >> x;
```

With the input of `0x1a` I get that `x == 0` and not `26`.

Why's that?

Comment: Well, it should be `cin >> x` for a start...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe in order to use hex you need to do something like this:

```
cin >> hex >> x;
cout << hex << x;
```

you can also replace hex with dec and oct etc.

Comment: If we haven't learned using hex yet, maybe the error is on purpose?

Comment: hex is part of the std library.

you can read more
[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/)

Comment: Does it work with binary as well? Something like `cout << bin << myInt;`?

Comment: you also need rename your data array, otherwise the array has the same name with the manipulator gonna cause trouble

Comment: @11684 no unfortunately there is no `bin` option. Seems there should be.

Comment: Don't forget to reset your streams after that. E.g `cin >> hex >> x >> dec;`

Answer (score 27):

Actually, You can force **`>>`** operator to get and properly interpret prefixes `0` and `0x`. All you have to do is to remove default settings for `std::cin`:

```
std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::dec);
std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::hex);
std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::oct);
```

Now, when you input 0x1a you will receive 26.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.
With hex if you do something like:
cin >> hex > x; and input 17 you will get 23 which is almost always not what you want as a user. With this method you get what any user want, prefix are taken in consideration. 23 gives 23, 0xa gives 0xa and so on.

Comment: They are both good answers, and it really depends on the application context to determine which you should use. Stroustrup goes over both in his book: both methods are useful to know. Both upvoted. Question upvoted. Everyone gets an upvote!

Comment: `std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::basefield);`

Answer (score 3):

Think of `<<` and `>>` when using `std::cout/std::cin` like so:

`std::cout << x` means get the value *from* `x`

`std::cin >> x` means put the value *into* `x`

Notice the directions in which the operators are pointing. That should give you a hint as to what they do when using these functions.

The reason that you are getting 0 as a result and not 26 is because `std::cin` will parse the all non numeric characters from your input. After all, `x` is an int, it won't recognize `0x` as a part of a hexadecimal number. It would of had the same behavior if the input was `9x2` (the result would simply be `9`).

Answer (score 2):

Your code should read:

```
int x;
cin >> hex >> x;
```

By default `cin` will expect any number read in to be decimal. Clearly, `0x1a` is not a valid decimal and so the conversion cannot take place. To get it to work we have to use the *stream modifier* `hex` which prompts `cin` to expect number conversion from hexadecimal rather than decimal.

The `0x` prefix is optional in this case so the input `10` would be read and stored as decimal 16.

Comment: Can you explain to the OP why?

Comment: Okay, but how would one ask `cin` to read hex instead? Is there a flag, as there is for `cout`?

Comment: There is no way that I know of other than than using the `std::hex` manipulator to set the basefield format flag on a stream. You can either use `operator<<` or `setf` on the stream to do this. By default, when `cin` is created, this is set to `std::dec`. This is the same for `std::cout`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int data[16];
    cout << "enter the 16 hexadecimal numbers\n";
    for(int i = 0;i < 16;i++)
    {
        if(cin >> hex >> data[i])
            cout << "input worked\n";
        else{
            cin.clear();
            cout << "invalid input\n";
        }
    }
}
```