# HEX String to various format

Tags: c++, hex

I need to convert a general HEX String to various format in C++, for example:

HEX string to unsigned int
HEX string to unsigned char
HEX string to unsigned short

What's the rapid solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex string (char \[\]) to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int)

Comment: look at these: `std::stringstream`, `std::hex`

Comment: can you please give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196589/getting-hex-through-cin also take a look at the "related" column on the ride side of stackoverflow.  It shows other questions about C++ converting hex strings

Comment: No code, no example, sorry. Try to do it somehow and we will point the problems out if it does not work.

Comment: i have resolved with : sscanf("HEX STRING", "%x", &my_field);

Comment: @user2543127 nice, but is not a C++ solution. it's C