# How to input letters and numbers using the same variable? (C++)

Tags: c++, variables, hex, calculator

I need a little bit of help with a hexadecimal calculator I'm trying to make. Hexadecimal calculations require to be able to read both the alphabet and the numbers. So how do I read and assign numerical values to the alphabets while still being able to read numbers? I need to be able to read values 0-9 and assign alphabets A-F with values of 10-15.

Comment: `std::string`, perhaps?

Comment: You don't need a special variable to store the A-F characters. Remember that all characters are represented as numbers internally.

Comment: what is the difference between: `int x = 15;` and `int x = 0xF`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can input a hex value using [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex).

For example:

```
int my_value;
std::cin >> std::hex >> my_value;
```

It also works with `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << std::hex << my_value;
```

Note that `my_value` is still treated as decimal by default.

Source: 
[Getting hex through Cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196589/getting-hex-through-cin)

---

Or you could do this:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
int hex = 0;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i)
{
    int temp = 0;
    if(input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')
        temp = (input[i] - '0');
    else if(input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'f')
        temp = (input[i] - 'a');
    else if(input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'F')
        temp = (input[i] - 'A');
    temp += i * 16;

    hex =+ temp;
}
```

A couple of notes:

- This uses ASCII `char` arithmetic. It's a bit unreadable.
- This converts `char` to `int`, might cause problems on some systems
- There's a bug if you add 0s to the left
- I didn't run this. Probably more bugs.

Comment: _"Note that `my_value` stores the value as decimal."_ I doubt that. It will be stored as a binary representation rather.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I used the following code and it seems to be working.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int xvar;
   
    cout <<"Please enter the number in hexadecimal or denary." << endl;
    std::cin >> std::hex >> xvar;
    
    std::cout << std::dec << xvar << endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << xvar << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: and here I thought I had to use if else statements. by the way, if I ever had to use something like that elsewhere, how would I input char and int using the same variable? I understood the hexadecimal application, but elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

you can use string

```
string s = "cb10"
```

about how to use, you can just

```
s[0] = 'a' //s = "ab10"
s[1] = '3' //s = "a310"
int i = s[1] - '0' //change char to int, i = 3
```

Comment: How does the calculation go for A-F, a-f?

Comment: ```int i = s[0] - 'a' + 10```

Comment: for A-F, int i = s[0] - 'A' + 10

Comment: seems like it is not smart at all...because it should be sorted before calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've been using this piece of code for a while now and it has been working perfectly. thanks all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int conv;

cout <<"Please enter appropriate command for conversion;" << endl;
cout <<"1. Hexadecimal to Denary." << endl;
cout <<"2. Denary to Hexadecimal." << endl;

cin >> conv;

if (conv == 1)
{
    int xvar;

    cout <<"Please enter the number in hexadecimal." << endl;

    std::cin >> std::hex >> xvar;

    std::cout << std::hex << xvar << endl;
    std::cout << std::dec << xvar << endl;
}

if (conv == 2)
{
    int yvar;

    cout <<"Please enter the number in denary." << endl;

    std::cin >> std::dec >> yvar;

    std::cout << std::dec << yvar << endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << yvar << endl;

}   
}
```